# Scifi series about random jumps to several timelines

Tags: story-identification

This is a series I saw a pair of chapters I think about 12 years ago. It looked like that the main plot of the series was a group of people that wanted to return to their own timeline and in the process of doing so they jumped into some random timeline where some big historical event had occured in a different way and they had to stay in that timeline for a while until the machine where they were traveling was recharged.

That's all I can renember.

Hope you can help me to identify which series is.

Comment: This perfectly describes the Netflix original [Parallels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallels_(film)), but you obviously couldn't have seen that 12 years ago.

Comment: so sad parallels didnt get picked up for a series

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Could it be the series *[Sliders](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sliders)*?

It features a group of people traveling through various parallel universes in an attempt to get to their own.

> The show follows a group of people, called "Sliders", as they travel ("sliding") between different Earths in parallel universes via a vortex-like wormhole, hoping to return safely to their original Earth Prime.

They didn't have to wait for their machine to recharge, but

> The vortex can only be opened after a specific but random period of time on each new universe, monitored by a countdown clock on a portable timer that they carry

It aired from 1995 to 1999, so you could have easily seen a rerun 12 years ago.

Comment: Looks like it. I'll check it. Thanks.

Comment: The first couple of seasons of *Sliders* resemble the question, before it became movie rip-off of the week.

Comment: Only the third season was really movie-ripoff heavy.  After that it got SLIGHTLY better, but still routinely awful writing.

Comment: You could say the characters in the show were a metaphor for the quality of the show itself, sliding each week, hoping to get back to where they were at the beginning.

Comment: Unfortunately Sliders was cut off mid story arc so it has a really disappointing ending that makes you think there is more, but there isn't.

Answer (score 3):

Another possibility, older: [The Time Tunnel](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0060036/)

They're trying to bring home their two scientists but each episode ends up with them using the tunnel to pull them out of a bad situation without having gotten it properly calibrated yet--and thus throwing them into next episode's problem rather than bringing them home.

Comment: That’s also the premise of *Quantum Leap*.